# Find a terminal DOM tree element that is rendered next to the right (or left) to a given one

Tags: jquery, html, dom

I have a semi-arbitrary DOM tree with an `INPUT` control somewhere in it. For example:

```
.terminal { white-space: no-wrap; display: inline-block; }

<div id="the-root">
  <span class="terminal">Alpha</span>
  <span><span class="terminal">Beta</span></span>
  <span>
     <span class="terminal"><input value="Gamma" /></span>
     <span><span class="terminal">Delta</span></span>
  </span>
  <span class="terminal">Epsilon</span>
</div>
```

`INPUT` may be placed inside any terminal element.

I need to find the next (as rendered) terminal element to the left and to the right of the `INPUT`. Is there an easy way to do this with jQuery?

Bonus points for a solution that also is able to find a terminal element directly above and below of the `INPUT` in case when there are so many entries that they span across several lines.

Here is a fiddle for you to play with: http://jsfiddle.net/g4oq1q35/

Comment: sorry... what do you mean by generic solution... what you have is working isn't it

Comment: It is working for this specific DOM tree. I need one that would work for any similar tree and any position of the input element.

Comment: I've changed the example a bit to illustrate that.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/8194ogr0/1/ ?

Comment: Excellent! Please post as an answer!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can try an index based solution

```
var $terminals = $('.terminal'),
    $terminal = $input.closest('.terminal'),
    idx = $terminals.index($terminal);
$terminals.eq(idx - 1).addClass('left');
$terminals.eq(idx + 1).addClass('right');
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/8194ogr0/)